# Outlook VBA - How to Deliver VBA and UserForms?

Tags: vba, outlook, packaging

In Outlook 2010 I coded a VBA and also have 2 user forms with some code.
How can I deliver the Module and the two forms as a package to my colleagues?
So they can easily add the VBA to Outlook 2010 and I can send them updates of my VBA.

Comment: Probably exporting the three modules from the VBE, zipping them with a text file for instructions, and sending an email

Comment: Microsoft goes to great lengths to protect Outlook from hacking.  Outlook has a much more robust security system than Word or Excel.  So the short answer is you cannot make it easy other than providing by detailed instructions.  Are you the only one writing Outlook macros?  I have never tried but downloading the file in which Outlook stores its macros, VbaProject.OTM, might be worth trying.